# overriding the dealloc method in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, dealloc

Can someone tell me what would actually happen if you override the dealloc method in Objective-C? As in would it crash or would it just start leaking memory all over the place. I've been wondering what would happen and why it is necessary to prevent the programmer from using dealloc directly.

And in what case would you had to do something like this?

**EDIT**: Sorry guys for not being clear. I was mainly talking in terms or ARC type coding.

Comment: If you are using ARC you normally wouldn't do this. If you aren't using ARC, you would use it to release things that you are retaining. I would take a look at the [Memory Management Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) from Apple to get more familiar with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before ARC overriding the `dealloc` method was very common, you were releasing the ivars the deallocated instance owned. Now, with ARC, is less common, however, you may have to do it in some special cases, like when you de-register an instance from observing with `NSNotificationCenter`.

The rule you talk about was not to call `dealloc` directly (not override), that would have usually led to a crash since you were bypassing Cocoa's internal reference counting system.

*Edit*: Based on your edit, if you call `[super dealloc]` under ARC, you'll get a compile time error. And if there was no error, it would have probably lead to duplicating the `dealloc` call, which would have made your program crash.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the example you give -- unregistering from NSNotificationCenter in the dealloc -- does not work, since `You must invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before any object specified by addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: is deallocated.`

Comment: scratch that. I got it wrong. Very good, +1 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582279/avoid-retain-cycles-nsnotificationcenter

Answer (score 16):

Overriding `-dealloc` is an extremely common thing to do in non-ARC code. In fact, you'd be hard-pressed to find a class that *doesn't* override it.

The key thing to remember, though, is that every single override of `-dealloc` always ends with a call to `[super dealloc]`.

Of course, in ARC code, overriding `-dealloc` is far less common. And if you do override it, you don't call `[super dealloc]`, because the compiler will insert that for you. But remember, this is only true under ARC.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I did not accept this answer because it didn't exactly answer my question of what would happen, not about it. +1

Comment: @nlee918: Well, Valentin didn't really tell you either. I thought the answer was implied really heavily when I said that it's a very common thing to do, which is "nothing bad". All I see is Valentin's comment about never *invoking* `-dealloc` directly. Is that what you meant to ask about? Because that's not in your question, and it really has no relation to *overriding* `-dealloc`.

Comment: @KevinBallard Well, I did tell him, but there was a confusion when reading the full answer. In the edit I've answered his edit and probably that's why nlee918 did get it. You were confused by the previous paragraph in which I talked about the direct call. My mistake. I've edited to be more clear.