# Avoid Retain Cycles, NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsnotificationcenter

Will this category method allow me to avoid additional retains on `NSNotificationCenter` observers?

```
#import "NSNotificationCenter+Util.h"

@implementation NSNotificationCenter (Util)

- (void)addWeakObserver:(nonnull NSObject*)observer selector:(nonnull SEL)aSelector name:(nullable NSString *)aName object:(nullable id)anObject {
    __weak NSObject *weakObserver = observer;
    [self addObserver:weakObserver selector:aSelector name:aName object:anObject];
}

@end
```

The goal is to have the object die without having to remove it.

---

**Note:** I'm trying to avoid this causing retain cycles:

> Be sure to invoke `removeObserver:name:object:` before
>   `notificationObserver` or any object specified in
>   `addObserver:selector:name:object:` is deallocated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No — `weakObserver` will be `weak`, so will automatically `nil` if `observer` is deallocated, but if `addObserver:...` retains the observer then it retains the observer. There's no history in an object as to the ways that previous references have held it, it's the references themselves that control their own behaviour.

However, `NSNotificationCenter` doesn't retain its observers, and observers almost never retain the notification centre. There is no retain cycle. The text you've quoted more or less says this: that pointers stored within the notification centre will become dangling, i.e. it is not asserting ownership.

What you've done also won't make the references stored within the centre automatically `nil`.

As of iOS 9 and OS X v10.11, this behaviour [is already fixed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter). A weak reference is used by the notification centre for all objects that can be referenced weakly.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that I was reading that wrong. But more importantly, I didn't know that "There's no history in an object as to the ways that previous references have held it, it's the references themselves that control their own behaviour." Fascinating.

Answer (score 14):

`NSNotificationCenter` doesn't retain `observer`, so you won't create a retain cycle just using `addObserver:selector:name:object:`. You don't need a wrapper method for that.

The reason for the warning about calling `removeObserver:name:object:` is because `NSNotificationCenter` didn't use zeroing weak references until OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) and iOS 9. In operating systems prior to these versions, if you fail to remove `observer` from the notification center when `observer` is deallocated, then the notification center will continue trying to send notifications to `observer`. This will generally cause a crash or worse.

If your deployment target is at least OS X 10.11 or iOS 9, then you don't have to worry about removing `observer` when it is deallocated.

Note that if you use `-[NSNotificationCenter -addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:]`, then I believe you do have to worry about avoiding a retain cycle caused by the block strongly retaining your observer.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was just scratching my head over in a Swift playground: no retain is actually taking place! This is great and very informative, thanks again.